# How to put values of different cycle of "for" in unique lists? python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

frames_ID is a nested list that contains several inner lists (trials). I want to calculate the velocity for each trial and keep the value for the velocity of each trial in a separate list.
My current code adds velocity for all trials into a single list (vel) and makes one big list. How can I change (vel) to a nested list that contains velocity for each trial in the unique lists?

```
vel=[]
for trial in range(len(frames_ID)):
    for k in range(len(frames_ID[trial])-1):
        if(frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k]) < -(np.pi): 
            velocity =((frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k])/(0.01)+ 2*np.pi) 
            vel.append(velocity)
        elif (frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k]) > np.pi: 
            velocity =((frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k])/(0.01)- 2*np.pi)
            vel.append(velocity)
        else:
            velocity =(frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k])/0.01

            vel.append(velocity)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do the following to create a nested sublist for each trial.

```
vel=[]
for trial in range(len(frames_ID)):
    vel.append([])           # add sublist for current trial
    for k in range(len(frames_ID[trial])-1):
        if(frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k]) < -(np.pi): 
            velocity =((frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k])/(0.01)+ 2*np.pi) 
            vel[-1].append(velocity)                 # append to last sublist for trial
        elif (frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k]) > np.pi: 
            velocity =((frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k])/(0.01)- 2*np.pi)
            vel[-1].append(velocity)                 # append to last sublist for trial
        else:
            velocity =(frames_ID[trial][k+1] - frames_ID[trial][k])/0.01

            vel[-1].append(velocity)                  # append to last sublist for trial
```